# Is there a way around Java's inability to forward generic arguments to non-generic types?

Tags: generics, kotlin

In C++ I can write code like this:

```
class Shader {
    ...
    void setUniform(GLuint handle, int value);
    void setUniform(GLuint handle, float value);
    void setUniform(GLuint handle, const std::vector<float> &value);
    ...
};

class UniformValueBase {
    ...
    GLuint handle;
    Shader &shader;
    virtual void apply() = 0;
};

template<typename T> class UniformValue: public UniformValueBase {
    ...
    T value;
    virtual void apply() override {
        shader.setUniform(handle, value);
};
```

and it will work when `T` is any type which has a `setUniform` method in `Shader`, and fail to compile if I try to use an unsupported `T`, which is exactly the behaviour I want.

Unfortunately the equivalent doesn't work in Java or Kotlin because generics are based on type erasure, meaning `UniformValue` is implemented only once with `T` as `Object`/`Any`.

I only need to support about half a dozen different types, so using non-generic subclasses of `UniformValueBase` instead of generics is workable, but is there an elegant and scalable idiom for this, either using a feature Kotlin has that Java doesn't, or one that works in both languages?

Comment: You won't be able to use the static `setUniform` overloads, instead you'll have to pass in a type tag (the class of the value). You can hold the values in a _heterogeneous map_ (published in Effective Java). In Kotlin some of the boilerplate may be reduced if you're able to apply the _reified type parameters_.

Comment: I've never taken the time to learn much about reflection in Java or Kotlin, but it doesn't look like it would help here. Kotlin uses `KClass` instead of `java.lang.Class` (although you can obtain the latter from the former), and `KClass` is itself generic.

Answer (score 2):

The basic reason is not really type erasure: it's because C++ templates are typechecked after instantiation and Java (and Kotlin and most other languages with this feature) typecheck the generic code itself. So you'd need a *constraint* requiring `T` to have a static method and neither Kotlin nor Java support those. The only language I know of which does is [F#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/constraints), which isn't available on JVM. Scala has a very nice and general workaround called typeclass pattern which isn't yet supported in Kotlin.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like that's not possible. Types are being erased in Java and there is no templates.